# laravel AES key generation without updating env file

Tags: php, laravel, aes

I am using `php artisan key:generate` for generating AES key,but it updating env file each time.

I need to generate a **unique AES key** for a chatroom.

Any suggestion will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you take a look at [the source of this command](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/1bbe5528568555d597582fdbec73e31f8a818dbc/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Console/KeyGenerateCommand.php#L59), you can find the function that is used to generate this key. If you want to use this key for something else, you can reuse this function.

```
protected function generateRandomKey()
{
    return 'base64:'.base64_encode(
        Encrypter::generateKey($this->laravel['config']['app.cipher'])
    );
}
```

Comment: need to encrypt a value with this newly generated key

Answer (score 2):

This will not update the env file:

```
php artisan key:generate --show
```